# What is ScriptSafe's "Client Rectangles" and what information does it leak?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, web, fingerprinting, fingerprint

Just wondering how this one affects the privacy and security because it breaks a lot of sites displaying images for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting
Although the worst privacy leak is always the smartphone.

Comment: @mootmoot Seems bad enough, will have to deal with broken sites unfortunately. I did find that before, but I thought it was for something different because of the naming...

Comment: Yes, the blocking is nasty, but the canvas fingerprinting make worst with smartphone devices : the canvas can easily pin point smartphone model. I.e. advertiser can mark up the product price when they detect the iphoneX  canvas, or malvertiser can craft phishing ads to convince the smartphone user.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Client Rectangles call is one of the abuse utilised by tracker/advertiser to profile the user(AKA Cavas fingerprinting).

Though this will not identify a person, but the tracking party can map the canvas resolution against the database( check this out :  [Mobile Device database](https://material.io/tools/devices/)) carry out targeting ads, price discrimination, malicious advertisement, phishing , blackmail ads etc.

Comment: How is it on the PC though? As I understand, they can still detect drivers and such, so it doesn't matter if my browser window is in random resolution, etc..

Comment: @Jack Desktop monitors resolution are pretty generic, so it will need other fingerprint bits.